# Конструкция if then else mysql

Tags: mysql

Как правильно написать запрос

```
SELECT

if 1=(select nds_purchase from orders_tehnika where id_orders_tehnika=777) 
THEN SUM((hours*1000)*18/118) as nds_purchase 
else 0 as nds purchase,

FROM worked_hours
```

Так же как сложить в другом запросе весь полученный результат используя SUMM

Comment: в mysql для использования в запросах есть конструкции `IF()` и `case..`, попробуйте начать со чтения [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: приведите пример исходных данных и результата вообще. а а то у вас тут какой то независимый подзапрос, и это несколько странно

Comment: ну если по русский если 1=(select nds_purchase from orders_tehnika where id_orders_tehnika=777) 
значит сделать SUM((hours*1000)*18/118) as nds_purchase 
иначе 0 as nds purchase,

Comment: просто не могу правильный синтаксис придумать